# Express Session Authentication Issue

Tags: node.js, json, express, session

I'm working on an Express.js application with session-based authentication.
After authenticating, I'm able to make a post request to /api, but when I try to make subsequent post requests to /api, it says not authenticated.

```
// imports ...

const app = express()

let data = JSON.parse(readFileSync('data.json'))

app.use(
    session({
        secret: 'secret-key',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
    })
)

app.use(express.json())

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    // some authentication logic
    req.session.authenticated = true
    res.send(`Authentication successful`)
})

// middleware for authentication
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.authenticated) {
        next()
    } else {
        res.send('Not Authenticated')
    }
}

app.post('/api', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    const { id, item } = req.body
    data.push({ id, item })
    writeFileSync('data.json', JSON.stringify(data))
    res.send(`Record added: ${id}, ${item}`)
})

...
```

What's wrong?